# Join SharePoint lists using a a SQL like SELECT statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql

I'm trying to figure way to join SharePoint lists using a a SQL like SELECT statement.

I have the following tables:

[customer details]

[customer notes]

[customer reviews]

all these have a common customer ID so I'm trying to do a SELECT across all three so that I can build a SharePoint list that will output the three tables when a customer number is entered in the search bar.

e.g.

select

Customer 101

RETURN

101[customer details]

101[customer notes]

101[customer reviews]

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at using Lookup Columns. These allow you to create relationships between lists the easiest approach.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer have a look at [joins and projections using caml](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539975(v%3Doffice.14)).
There is no "SQL-Like syntax" for SharePoint.

Additionally, as a "rule of thumb": If you can build a relational model of your data, most probably SharePoint is not the best way to store the data.

Comment: Thanks Nils I agree on shrepoint is not the best way to store data, is there anything in office365 that would give me SQL abilities?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could try connecting PowerBI (check https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/integrations/sharepoint/ ) or Excel.. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that can be achieved using SharePoint search and content types.
https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/display-search-results-in-sharepoint-online-b4784d48a9d5

Answer (score 0):

I Ended up using lookup columns which seem to have worked very well for me.
I put all the data until 1 table rather than taking a normalisation approach from the database theory.